# Android: EditText take out remaining space

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an edit text item that I want to have take up the top portion of the screen (everything except for the area denoted as the button container), but I am really struggling with doing so. I would like to not set exact heights (in dp) as I fear they may not scale well with other devices. Any ideas?

[image: Desired layout]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myScreen"
    style="@style/Activity"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tbx"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/video_note_hint"
            style="@style/TitleText_Second_NotBold">
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_next_height_half"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/delete_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_selector"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_discard"/>


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/saveNote"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_next_height_half"  <!-- 60dp -->
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_selector"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_save" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit** I forgot to include some styles:

```
<style name="TitleText_Second_NotBold" parent="@style/TitleText_Master">
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
</style>

<style name="TitleText_Master">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Comment: and `@style/TitleText_Second_NotBold` is what?

Comment: Sorry about that. See edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the layout with EditText, set height to 0dp and add `android:layout_weight="1"`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a RelativeLayout and attach the bottom of the text to the button group.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html